# PDFBOX: Convert a pdf to text or html, including images from the pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am developing a mobile application that converts pdf to html. I found PDFBox, which works very well. I obtained the PDF text or html on one side and the other images.
But I want to go a little further, I need the generated html contains the images in the pdf.
Can it be done with PDFBox? How?
If you know of another free library function to do this, tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ExtractImages.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.java?view=markup) - this will guide you on how to extract images from PDF file.

Next investigate the [PrintImageLocations.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java?view=markup) example - you will need those locations to properly format HTML file.

Comment: Thanks, I had this idea but it is very complex to work with the coordinates x and y. Now I'm trying to find the place that parses the images, then try to modify them.